# jQuery Masonry infinite scroll

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry, infinite-scroll

I have infinite scroll working using the Masonry plugin and images are appended to the web page on scroll.  See below:

```
 <script>
   (function () {
    var $tumblelog = $('#container');
    $tumblelog.infinitescroll({
        navSelector: ".pagination",
        nextSelector: ".pagination a:first-child",
        itemSelector: "article",
    },

    function (newElements) {


        var $newElems = $(newElements).css({
            opacity: 0
        });


        $newElems.imagesLoaded(function () {
            $newElems.animate({
                opacity: 1
            });
            $tumblelog.masonry('appended', $newElems);


        });
    });



    $tumblelog.imagesLoaded(function () {

        $tumblelog.masonry({
            itemSelector: '.rollover',
            columnWidth: 425
        });
    });
})();
</script>
```

The initial set of images are each contained within a div, class name "rollover".  I am using JQuery hover function whenever the mouse hovers over the rollover div, which hides the image within it.  See below:

```
$(window).load(function() {

   $('div.rollover').hover(
  function () {

       $(this).children('.thumb').hide(); 
  },
  function () {

      $(this).children('.thumb').show(); 
  });

});
```

When I hover over the initial set of images they disappear and reappear as intended.  But when I hover over the appended images nothing happens.  Any pointers please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [JQuery's live() event](http://api.jquery.com/live/). When you are creating hover event handler elements that will be appended don't exist. `.live()` also handles future elements. Code:

```
$(window).load(function() {

   $('div.rollover').live("hover", 
  function () {

       $(this).children('.thumb').hide(); 
  },
  function () {

      $(this).children('.thumb').show(); 
  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks very much.  The live() event is now deprecated.  I used the on() event instead.

Comment: No problem. Good luck with your project!